# attempt to call global `print' (a nil value)

Tags: c, lua, embedding

I have the following C file:

```
//thing.c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

lua_State* L;

int main(){
        L = lua_open();

        lua_dostring(L, "print(\"lua\")");
        printf("hello\n");

        return 0; }
```

and the following makefile:

```
default:
        gcc -I/usr/include/lua50 -L/usr/lib -o qwerty thing.c -llua50 -llualib50
```

the code builds just fine, but when I run it I get the following:

```
[string "print("lua")"]:1: attempt to call global `print' (a nil value)
hello
```

**Note**: I have seen the many other questions on this error, but they all deal with working directly in Lua, as opposed to with the C api.  They also seem to imply that the problem is that the `print` function was never defined.  I don't understand this, as I can run both a lua interpreter and a lua script just fine directly from the command line.

**EDIT**: I am using lua 5.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to initialize the libraries in Lua. After you call `lua_open`, call

```
luaL_openlibs(L);
```

**Edit**: for Lua 5.0, I believe you'll have to open the libraries manually. For the `print` function, you just need the base library:

```
luaopen_base(L);
```

Comment: `thing.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'luaL_openlibs'` Noteworthy:  I am using lua 5.0

Comment: @ewok, see edit. However, since you're getting a linking error (and not a compiler error), I think you may be including the 5.1 or 5.2 header, but linking the 5.0 library. I see you're specifying the 5.0 include path, but I wonder if you have the 5.1 or 5.2 headers somewhere in your default include path?